# How are IN expressions executed in SQL queries internally?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

I have query with an `IN` clause.

```
select * from student where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How will the engine parsed and execute this SQL query?
Is it like this, parsed in five different queries or something else?

```
select * from student where id = 1
select * from student where id = 2
select * from student where id = 3
select * from student where id = 4
select * from student where id = 5
```

Comment: Use EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see how PostgreSQL executes your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Postgres query planner translates [`IN` with a list (row) expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19674):

```
select * from student where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

exactly like this:

```
select * from student where id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5;
```

You can see this if you run the statement with `EXPLAIN`.

Note that there are two basic forms of `IN`. Details in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your valuable comments. Here i have one more suggestions, whether two many in conditions will effect performance? If so, whether spiting queries will help us to improve performance? Please leave me your valuable suggestions

Comment: @VijayThayalan: There is [advice for better performance in answer I inked to](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684). Similar [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql/61552#61552)

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not do that although the five queries and the one query will return the same result (assuming no modifications to the table while running five queries).  The five queries would require scanning the `student` table five times, once for each query.  The "scan" might actually use an index an be really fast.

The five queries also need to be compiled and executed, which add additional overhead.

With the `in`, you are executing one query.  Without an index, Postgres will look at each row to see if it matches.  If so, it goes in the result set.  With an index, it will just look up the appropriate rows in the index.

Comment: I did not get you Gordan. Are you saying that the 'IN' condition will not run as separate queries? If we have two 'IN' condition in a single query with two different tables, will that run two single query? Like one query for first table and another query for second table. Please give your comments :)

Comment: @VijayThayalan: one query is executed as one query regardless of the conditions.